# Azure Logic App configuration with continuation token

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have following setting-up for Logic app for deleting entries from Azure Storage Table. It works fine, but there is problem if in storage table is more than 1K entities. In this case were deleted only oldest 1K entities and rest remains in table ...
I found that this is caused by 1K batch limit and that there is "continuation token", which is provided in this case.
Question is how I can include this continuation into my workflow?

Thank you much for help.

So ... I dont have enough reputation points to post image - I try describe it:

Get Entities ([Table])

->

For each ([Get entities result List of Entities])

->

Delete Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only return 1000 records because the `Pagination` default is off. So go to the Settings, set the `Pagination` on and set the `Threshold` a large enough number. I test with 2000, it will return all records.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even in this official doc doesn't mention Azure Table, however it does have a limits, further more information about Pagination refer to this doc:[Get more data, items, or records by using pagination in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exceed-default-page-size-with-pagination).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, we cannot get the continuationToken header with the Azure Table Storage action. This function might not be implemented for Table Storage action.

The workaround could be to use [Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops) action, and repeat checking for existing entities.

The continuationToken is included in some actions. For example: the Azure CosmosDB action. You can utilize it with these actions. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-logic-apps-recipes-cosmosdb-connector-retrieve-shree-divya-mv/) for how to use it.
[image]